# Outlier value missing

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I have this code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \begin{axis}[samples=101,smooth,height=9cm,ymin =0,
            boxplot/draw direction=y,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick={200,400,600,1200,1400,2675,4000},ytick pos=left,boxplot/variable width,      
            ]
            \addplot+ [boxplot ={lower whisker=400, lower quartile=600, median=1200, upper quartile=1400, upper whisker=2675}, ] coordinates {(0,200)(0,4000)};
            
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,4000)} node[pin=0:{Valor atípico}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,2675)} node[pin=15:{ $P_{75}+1.5\cdot RIC(X)$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,400)} node[pin=-15:{ $P_{25}-1.5\cdot RIC(X)$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1.075,1200)} node[pin=0:{$Q_{2}=Me$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1.075,600)} node[pin=0:{$Q_{1}$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1.075,1400)} node[pin=15:{$Q_{3}$}]{} ;   
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,200)} node[pin=180:{Valor atípico}]{} ; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\captionof*{figure}{Without prepared:  No lower outlier}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        \begin{axis}[samples=101,smooth,height=9cm,ymin =0,
            boxplot/draw direction=y,
            xtick=\empty,
            ytick={200,400,600,1200,1400,2675,4000},ytick pos=left,boxplot/variable width,      
            ]
            \addplot+ [boxplot prepared ={lower whisker=400, lower quartile=600, median=1200, upper quartile=1400, upper whisker=2675,box extend =0.5,}, ] coordinates {(0,200)(0,4000)};
            
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,4000)} node[pin=0:{Valor atípico}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,2675)} node[pin=15:{ $P_{75}+1.5\cdot RIC(X)$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,400)} node[pin=-15:{ $P_{25}-1.5\cdot RIC(X)$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1.075,1200)} node[pin=0:{$Q_{2}=Me$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1.075,600)} node[pin=0:{$Q_{1}$}]{} ;
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1.075,1400)} node[pin=15:{$Q_{3}$}]{} ;   
            \addplot[mark=none] coordinates {(1,200)} node[pin=180:{Valor atípico}]{} ; 
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}\captionof*{figure}{With prepared: outlier but messed width up}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, in first one, there is no outlier at (0,200), but the point is within range

On second one I get the two outliers, but box size qets wild.

I tried modifying second one with `box extend =0.5,` order bur it didn't work.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The width difference is a result of using `boxplot/variable width` I think. See the description in the manual:

[image]

Add e.g. `sample size=1` to the second one, and it looks like you get the same width.

Regarding the missing outlier, I'm not sure why that happens. But as I understand it, with `boxplot` you're supposed to supply the data, and `pgfplots` calculates the whiskers, quartiles and median. Why can't you just use `boxplot prepared`, which is the intended method when you have precomputed values?

A slightly more concise example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
           \begin{axis}[
            boxplot/draw direction=y,
            boxplot/variable width=true, 
            ]
            \addplot+ [
            boxplot ={
               lower whisker=400,
               lower quartile=600,
               median=1200,
               upper quartile=1400,
               upper whisker=2675}
               ] coordinates {(0,200)(0,4000)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            boxplot/draw direction=y,
            boxplot/variable width=true, 
            ]
            \addplot+ [
              boxplot prepared ={
                sample size=1,     % <-- added
                lower whisker=400,
                lower quartile=600,
                median=1200,
                upper quartile=1400,
                upper whisker=2675}
                ] coordinates {(0,200)(0,4000)};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sample size=1 was the key code.  Thak you very much!!!!